# double quote inside single quote in angular1.x directive not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am creating an angular directive as shown below to display a logo in the header. the background image is not appearing and i doubt this is because of wrong quotes inside single quote. can anyone please help me to fix this?

```
angular.module("Common")
            .directive("mainHeader", [
                function () {
                    /// <summary>Markup for the main header section</summary>
                    return {
                        restrict: "E",
                        template: 
    '<header class="row"' +
        '<div class="col-md-12 logo-container">' +
            '<div class="logo" style="background:url(""/Content/Images/ey_login_logo.png""/) left top no-repeat;"></div>' +
        '</div>' +      
    '</header>'
                    };
                }
            ])
```

The output i am getting for the above code is :

```
<div class="logo" style="background:url(" "="" content="" images="" ey_login_logo.png""="" )="" left="" top="" no-repeat;"=""></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<header` isn't closed with `>` (typo?)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thank you. It worked

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thank you.

Comment: This problem can be avoided by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove double quotes from the `url` section  in `style` part

`style="background:url(/Content/Images/ey_login_logo.png/) left top no-repeat;"`

Comment: I think it's just a typo error and the question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be avoided by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
angular.module("Common")
.directive("mainHeader", function () {
    /// <summary>Markup for the main header section</summary>
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template:` 
.       <header class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 logo-container">
            <div class="logo" style="background:url(/Content/Images/ey_login_logo.png) left top no-repeat;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>`
    };
})
```